# No internet connection using OpenVPN Android clients

Tags: server, android, openvpn

I have an issue connecting to my OpenVPN server using an Android client.

I've just installed it using the script provided on 
https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install (openvpn-install.sh);

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Basically I can connect without errors using any Android OpenVPN clients (I tried a few), but there is no internet connections. Android version 5.1. 
Everything is fine (INCLUDING INTERNET NAVIGATION) using the openvpn-networkmanager plugin on my Ubuntu laptops - connected trough 3G hotspot.

This is the content of `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` on the Ubuntu server:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

THIS IS THE JOURNALCTL LOG immediately AFTER LAUNCHING THE VPN CLIENT ON ANDROID - THEN VPN ON MY LAPTOP (HP) IS STARTED:

> asds@asds-desk:~$ journalctl --since 14:47

`Mar 25 15:47:01 asds-desk sslh[2185]: connection from modemtelecom.homenet.telecomitalia.it:52106 to asds-desk.homenet.telecomitalia.
Mar 25 15:47:03 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 TLS: new session incoming connection from [AF_INET]176.200.108.
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 CRL CHECK OK: CN=ChangeMe
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 CRL CHECK OK: CN=m3s
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=m3s
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for H
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for H
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 TLS: move_session: dest=TM_ACTIVE src=TM_UNTRUSTED reinit_src=1
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 TLS: tls_multi_process: untrusted session promoted to semi-trus
Mar 25 15:47:04 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM
Mar 25 15:47:05 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Mar 25 15:47:05 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
Mar 25 15:47:05 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: m3s/176.200.108.67:48988 SENT CONTROL [m3s]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dh
Mar 25 15:47:33 asds-desk sslh[2185]: connection from modemtelecom.homenet.telecomitalia.it:52023 to asds-desk.homenet.telecomitalia.
Mar 25 15:48:05 asds-desk sslh[2185]: connection from modemtelecom.homenet.telecomitalia.it:57946 to asds-desk.homenet.telecomitalia.
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]176.200.108.67:48819, sid=1ef5e4e
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 CRL CHECK OK: CN=ChangeMe
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 CRL CHECK OK: CN=hp
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=hp
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC 
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC 
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: 176.200.108.67:48819 [hp] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]176.200.108.67:48819
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: hp/176.200.108.67:48819 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.5, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Mar 25 15:48:11 asds-desk ovpn-server[1475]: hp/176.200.108.67:48819 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.5 -> hp/176.200.108.67:48819`

Comment: Have you previously had a VPN up, the tun0 interface may need to be taken down so you can start it again. I had mine get stuck before... what is your journalctl telling you about the net connection, it may just be your dns

Comment: What version of Android are you using? One of the older ones had a system bug and OpenVPN simply wouldn't work right.

Comment: You are not testing the laptops by connecting to the server via wifi on the same LAN are you? If you're not connecting from an external IP, your results may be a false positive.

Comment: Following the above comments: added android version (5.1) / laptop tested using my phone 3G hotspot / systemctl log pasted. Do you see anything useful to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you verify whether you have internet via VPN on Android and on laptop via the local net? Simply make VPN connection within your LAN using ovpn server LAN address.